# Выбор файла в input

Tags: javascript, html, input

При загрузке страницы хочу задавать значению input(типа file) определенную картинку, которая лежит на сервере. Может кто-то знает как это можно сделать?

Comment: `input { background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat; }`

Answer (score 3):

Инпут для файла содержит файл, который ввёл пользователь, файл на его компьютере. Файл на сервере это не файл пользователя, с точки зрения клиента это ссылка. Насколько мне известно, сейчас добавить ссылку как файл в input нельзя.

Чтобы пользователь видел загруженный ранее файл в форме, обычно выводят имя файла (можно превью, если это изображение) рядом с инпутом файла.

UPD

Я заблуждался. Всё-таки вариант добавить своё значение есть.

```js
var dt = new DataTransfer();
var file = new File([''], 'filename');
dt.items.add(file)
var fileEl = document.querySelector('input');
fileEl.files = dt.files;
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

В примере я создаю файл-пустышку, но можно и загрузить его.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете установить значение по умолчанию в `<input type='file'>` из соображений безопасности. Сложно представить зачем вообще может понадобиться передавать картинку с сервера в значение по умолчанию input-a. Возможно вам стоит пересмотреть свою архитектуру. Или описать детальней задачу здесь и вам, возможно, предложат другое решение.